# Method references for non-empty arguments?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I was reading about the [Java 8 features](http://www.techempower.com/blog/2013/03/26/everything-about-java-8/) and I saw that they have method references, but I did not see how to specify which method when the method is overloaded. Does anyone know?

Comment: Since lambda expressions are shorthands for functional interfaces the type of the method should be inferable from the method in the interface.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings: This doesn't refer to lambda expressions, but to method references, which are different.  A lambda expression is an implementation of a function; a method reference is a reference to a preexisting method from a preexisting class.

Comment: @LouisWasserman According to the article to which I linked, method references are going to be implemented as lambdas hence my tag.

Comment: Why did you accept an answer, which doesn’t answer your question even remotely?

Comment: @Holger It is answered, it's the one with the signature that matches the functional type, or you might need to cast to a specific type if necessary to disambiguate. I'll edit the answer to spell it out.

Comment: I reverted your edit, because this is not what the answer said. Neither, the cited FAQ part, nor the example address this topic. If you have to add the actual answer to make it an answer to your question, then, well, it is not an answer to your question.

Comment: @Holger `Cast expressions, which provide the target type explicitly.` answered my question. "Casting" method references answered my question. That was the answer. My edit illustrated the connection from that line to the answer I needed.

Comment: Of course, anyone could throw “casting” into the ring, without even knowing Java 8 nor method references, not to speak of your question. The fact is, the cited FAQ has nothing to do with your question, as its about what happens when lambda expressions are passed as argument to other methods and neither have the examples. See, your question is about *method references* and the entire answer is *completely unrelated to method references*. Actually, the correct answer is that the right method will be chosen from context, *without the need for type casting* in most of the cases.

Comment: @Holger Yes, but in the ambiguous cases (ie where it gets interesting) it requires casting. Well it's not real "casting" it's using casting syntax to indicate suggest what the type signature expected is. So the selected answer was not complete it's second example answered the question if you connect a few dots yourself. If you've got a better answer feel free to submit and let the community upvote it.

Comment: Casting to a different target type only makes sense, if you have a choice. Normally, there is *one* target type and this will cause the selection one of the overloads, if you use a method reference to an overloaded method. However, if that’s not the intended one, there is no way to pick another one, as casting to a different target type means, the resulting object is unusable in its context. Casting can only help, if you want to pass the method reference as argument to another method, which is also overloaded with different functional interfaces. Your question never mentioned such a scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this Lambda FAQ](http://www.lambdafaq.org/):

> **Where can lambda expressions be used?**
>
> - Method or constructor arguments, for which the target type is the type of the
>   appropriate parameter. If the method or constructor is overloaded, the
>   usual mechanisms of overload resolution are used before the lambda
>   expression is matched to the target type. (After overload resolution,
>   there may still be more than one matching method or constructor
>   signature accepting different functional interfaces with identical
>   functional descriptors. In this case, the lambda expression must be
>   cast to the type of one of these functional interfaces);
> - Cast expressions, which provide the target type explicitly. For example:

```
Object o = () -> { System.out.println("hi"); };       // Illegal: could be Runnable or Callable (amongst others)
Object o = (Runnable) () -> { System.out.println("hi"); };    // Legal because disambiguated
```

So, you'll need to cast it if there are ambiguous signatures.

Answer (score 6):

Compiler will match the method signature with the functional interface.

```
Integer foo(){...}

Integer foo(Number x){...}

Supplier<Number>          f1 = this::foo;  // ()->Number, matching the 1st foo

Function<Integer, Number> f2 = this::foo;  // Int->Number, matching the 2nd foo
```

Essentially, `f2` is something that can accept an `Integer` and return a `Number`, the compiler can find out that the 2nd `foo()` meets the requirement.