# method reference vs lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

I want to replace lambda expression by method reference in the below example :

```
 public class Example {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<String> words = Arrays.asList("toto.", "titi.", "other");
         //lambda expression in the filter (predicate)
            words.stream().filter(s -> s.endsWith(".")).forEach(System.out::println);
        }
   }
```

I want to write a something like this :

```
words.stream().filter(s::endsWith(".")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

is it possible to transform any lambda expression to method reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method references for non-empty arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667804/method-references-for-non-empty-arguments)

Comment: thank you for your response. can you show me please transformation in my case because with (s::endsWith(".") ) i get a  compilation error.

Comment: You can't use `::` if the argument is on the instance call. You can replace `s -> "hi".equals(s)` with `"hi"::equals` but not if it's `s -> s.equals("hi")`

Comment: thank you Peter. It's very clear now. so in my case it's not possible

Comment: under the hood MethodHandle [can shuffle arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html#permuteArguments-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-int...-), but this is not exposed in the java method reference syntax and I wonder if it would actually be any faster after inling. scala on the other hand can do that with partially applied functions

Comment: @the8472: `MethodHandle` can shuffle arguments, but the result is not a direct method handle anymore and `LambdaMetaFactory` does support direct method handles only. Partially applied functions, on the other hand, would work, as they don’t shuffle arguments, and LMF supports left-to-right parameter binding. So for `.endsWith(".")`, where the right parameter ought to be bound, no chance…

Comment: The syntax for a method reference would be `String::endsWith`, plus some hypothetical way to bind the `"."` argument. What’s the advantage over `s -> s.endsWith(".")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way “to transform any lambda expression to method reference”, but you can implement a factory for a particular target type, if this serves recurring needs:

```
public static <A,B> Predicate<A> bind2nd(BiPredicate<A,B> p, B b) {
    return a -> p.test(a, b);
}
```

with this, you can write

```
words.stream().filter(bind2nd(String::endsWith, ".")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

but actually, there’s no advantage. Technically, a lambda expression does exactly what you want, there’s the minimum necessary argument transformation code, expressed as the lambda expression’s body, compiled into a synthetic method and a method reference to that synthetic code. The syntax
`s -> s.endsWith(".")` also is already the smallest syntax possible to express that intent. I doubt that you can find a smaller construct that would still be compatible with the rest of the Java programming language.

Comment: why when i use : Supplier<String> x=String::toUpperCase; i get "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method toUpperCase() from the type String" but when i use BiPredicate<String,String> x=String::endsWith; this work fine

Comment: How is `toUpperCase` supposed to be a `Supplier`? It requires a `String` to convert to upper case, so you have to use a function type that consumes a `String`, e.g. `Function<String,String>` or `UnaryOperator<String>`. Or you bind an instance like `Supplier<String> x="foo"::toUpperCase`, but there is not much use in a supplier that always supplies `"FOO"`…

Answer (score 3):

You can use `selectWith()` from [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/). `selectWith()` takes a [Predicate2](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/block/predicate/Predicate2.html) which takes 2 parameters instead of a `Predicate`. The second parameter to `selectWith()` gets passed as the second parameter to the `Predicate2` every time it's called, once per item in the iterable.

```
MutableList<String> words = Lists.mutable.with("toto.", "titi.", "other");
words.selectWith(String::endsWith, ".").each(System.out::println);
```

By default Eclipse Collections is eager, if you want to iterate lazily then you can use `asLazy()`

```
words.asLazy().selectWith(String::endsWith, ".").each(System.out::println);
```

If you can't change from `List`:

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("toto.", "titi.", "other");
ListAdapter.adapt(words).selectWith(String::endsWith, ".").each(System.out::println);
```

Eclipse Collections' [RichIterable](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/RichIterable.html) has several other *With methods which work well with method references, including `rejectWith()`, `partitionWith()`, `detechWith()`, `anySatisfyWith()`, `allSatisfyWith()`, `noneSatisfyWith()`, `collectWith()`

Note: I am a contributor to Eclipse Collections.