# Is there a Java method reference for arithmetic addition?

Tags: java, java-stream, method-reference

When using streams in Java, is it possible to use a method reference for arithmetic addition (rather than a lambda)?

At the moment (to sum the contents of a stream) I am using `stream.reduce(0, (x, y) -> x + y)`, but I would like to use something like `stream.reduce(0, Math::add)`, if it exists.

---

On a more general but similar note, does *every* method/operation in Java have a method reference?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#sum--, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#sum--

Comment: why not to create your own add method?

Comment: Pertaining to another question, *does every method/operation in Java have a method reference* - Take a look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215509/method-reference-vs-lambda-expression).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can use `Integer.sum`,

```
stream.reduce(0, Integer::sum)
```

Or you can convert the stream to an `IntStream` and just call `sum`

```
stream.mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
```

Comment: Or `Long::sum`, `Float::sum` or `Double::sum`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Math.addExact](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#addExact-int-int-)

```
stream.reduce(0, Math::addExact)
```